# Getting higher number of aws snapshot than the snapshots I've in my AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, amazon-ebs

When I try to do :

```
conn = boto.connect_ec2(access_key = "xxxxxxx", access_secret = "yyyyyy")
snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots()
```

I get different number of snapshots(more than snapshots I see on console)

but when try to execute

`snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots(owner="xxxxxyyyyyyy")`

I get real number of snapshot that I see on console.

Why is that behaviour in boto. Where I can find those extra snaphots.

Comment: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2031

Comment: Thnx that helped .. .!
Should've looked into paramters ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots()
```

^ Returns all the snapshot that you've access to. It may be many public accessible snapshots.

```
snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots(owner="xxxxxyyyyyyy")  OR snapshots = conn.get_all_snapshots(owner="self")
```

xxxxxyyyyyy > AWS_Account_ID

^^ Returns the the snapshots you own.

Thnx to:  [@BMW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498256/bmw)

Reference : https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2031